# Using Google sheet checkbox as conditional in calculation

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to have a Google Sheet checkbox and do some calculation based on it.

Ex (pseudocode):

```
if B1 is checked:
    A1=(B5*A20)/12*100
else
    A1=(B5*A20)/12*200
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do try the following formula

```
=IF(B1=TRUE,(B5*A20)/12*100,(B5*A20)/12*200)
```

It works because when a box is checked, it results to `TRUE`. When not to `FALSE`.